# When will Windows Server 2019 VMs be supported in GCE?

Tags: google-compute-engine, windows-server

When will Windows Server 2019 VMs be supported in GCE?

Both as custom images and pre-built images.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product/service roadmap question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2019 is not fully available from Microsoft. Installation media has not been released (ISO images are available).

Subscribe to [Google Cloud Blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/) to stay up to date on Google announcements.

You can follow general Windows Server 2019 availability [here](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/windowsserver/2018/11/13/update-on-windows-server-2019-availability/).

StackOverflow is a great place for programming and development questions. This is not the place to ask marketing or customer support questions.